# Mistake with return variable declaration

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int Add_Array_Backwards(int * a , int f) /*array a, f is length and is used for exponent multiplication*/
{
    for(int i=f-1; i>=0 ; i--) /*i ends at 0, first element of array should not be exponentiated*/
    {
        int backwards_sum = 0;
        backwards_sum = backwards_sum + a[i]*(pow(10,i)); //function to flip numbers
    }
        return backwards_sum; //final sum

}

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int f=5;
    int x = Add_Array_Backwards(a,f);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

I Wrote a function that takes the elements within an array, and multiplies them exponentially from the back to the front(the numbers at the front or end of the array are the greatest and appear first in the new integer sum). Meaning that the array will be flipped and added to appear as one number. Ex: An array with {1,2,3,4,5} will return a sum of 54321. The equation "backwards_sum = backwards_sum + a[i]*(pow(10,i));" is supposed to take a sum that starts at 0, and is added on to by the elements of the array to resemble the wanted outcome of reversing the array. The math is right and I checked myself, the problem is returning the sum. When I try to return int backwards_sum in place of int x in main, I get this error in output:

/*main.c: In function ‘Add_Array_Backwards’:
main.c:11:16: error: ‘backwards_sum’ undeclared (first use in this function)

11 |         return backwards_sum;
|                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.c:11:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
*/

I think there's something wrong with how I implemented the equation syntactically and the compiler is missing a piece of information so it can't return what I want it to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: backwards_sum only exists within the scope of the for loop. Move its definition to above the for loop.

Comment: the math would be wrong anyway. `backwards_sum` is reinitialized to 0 each iteration of the loop. Read up on variable scoping.

Comment: Your declaration of `backwards_sum` inside the loop sets it to zero on *each loop iteration*.  This makes no sense.  Move it out of the loop where it belongs.

Comment: BTW, you [don't need `pow`](https://godbolt.org/z/Wb34xdbzv) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the feedback provided to the OP:

1. the scope of `backwards_sum` is limited to the `for` loop. Trying to return its value triggers the compiler error. The definition of `backwards_sum` should be moved outside the `for` loop.
2. using `pow` isn't actually necessary but, in case it is used and depending on the compiler/environment, it might require a `-lm` flag added to the compiler's options, to make the linker happy.
3. The size of the array `a` passed to the `Add_Array_Backwards` function doesn't have to be hardcoded but can be computed using `sizeof`.

The following version of the program addresses item #1 and #3, and uses `pow` (to be compiled with the `-lm` flag to link against `libm.a`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int Add_Array_Backwards(int * a , int f) /*array a, f is length and is used for exponent multiplication*/
{
    int backwards_sum = 0;
    for(int i=f-1; i>=0 ; i--) /*i ends at 0, first element of array should not be exponentiated*/
        backwards_sum += a[i]*(pow(10,i)); //function to flip numbers
    
    return backwards_sum; //final sum

}

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    size_t f = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    int x = Add_Array_Backwards(a,f);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Alternatively, it is possible to do without `pow`, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Add_Array_Backwards(int * a , int f) /*array a, f is length and is used for exponent multiplication*/
{
    int backwards_sum = 0;
    for(int i=f-1; i>=0 ; i--) /*i ends at 0, first element of array should not be exponentiated*/
        backwards_sum = backwards_sum*10 + a[i]; //function to flip numbers
    
    return backwards_sum; //final sum

}

int main() {
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    size_t f = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    int x = Add_Array_Backwards(a,f);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```